# google play badges language

Tags: android, google-play, badge

I've just upload my app to Google Play, and now I would like to add the Google Play badge to my website.

But I only find this badge in  [English:](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/distribute/googleplay/promote/badges.html)

Does it exists in any other languages? If not, may I change the text to translate it into my language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the "Android app on" - text? I don't see any reason why you could not change it to match your language. Until you are not claiming any of google names and/or logos to be your own, you are not violating against any rules